# I can't get past the remotebuild part of the installation tutorial for visual studio for Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to setup a developing environment using visual studio for Mac and Cordova - Ionic.
So at this point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/first-steps/ios-guide?view=toolsforcordova-2017#secure-mode of the tutorial I should run

```
remotebuild
```

and I get the following error:

```
| => remotebuild
Warning: No server modules selected. Defaulting to configuration "modules": {"taco-remote": { "mountPath": "cordova"} }
Error: Unable to load module taco-remote. Try running 'npm install taco-remote' or specifying the full path to the package
****** Failed to start server: ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:27:35
    at req_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/remotebuild/node_modules/natives/index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/remotebuild/node_modules/natives/index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/remotebuild/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/remotebuild/node_modules/applicationinsights/AutoCollection/Exceptions.js:25
                    throw error;
                    ^

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:27:35
    at req_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/remotebuild/node_modules/natives/index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/remotebuild/node_modules/natives/index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/remotebuild/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
```

I'm stuck... any help?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the command you can try

```
$ npm install -g n
$ sudo n 11.15.0
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: this cmd lines has solved my problem but what's that mean, Am i lost the lts version of npm ?